# Virtualbox 6.1 Memory Hogging

Tags: virtualbox, systemd

I am on Ubuntu desktop 20.04 and I run a web server inside virtualbox box which on b/c I launch the VM via a custom systemd service file.

**Problem:**
For reasons unknown to me vboc is hogging all of my systems memory by launching multiple copies of the same process as seen here:
[image]

This is my systemd config for launching virtualbox:

`/etc/systemd/system/VminRoot2.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Vmin-Vbox
After=network.target virtualbox.service
Before=runlevel2.target shutdown.target
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
User=root
Group=vboxusers
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm VminRoot2 --type headless
ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm VminRoot2 acpipowerbutton
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

These are the  settings for my machine:
[image]

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?  How can I get vbox to launch... once  ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's one process with multiple threads. Notice how the resource consumption across all those entries are the same. As for why the virtual machine is consuming as many resources as it is, that would depend wholly on what is being served and how you've configured the instance limits 

Comment: @matigo They all have different process id s  and some have different nice levels... (I will upload a better image in a moment)...  And my box settings are pretty simple... doesn't explaing consumption... will post those as well...

Comment: @matigo unless I am mistaken they are all different processes  `ps -o ppid= -p 1650851` yields no result. nor does it for any of the other process ids.  They are all "parent" processes

Comment: @matigo  found the most unlikely culprit of all time eating my memory... 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424014/apache2-not-installed-but-consuming-memory

Comment: @matigo figured out the "mystery"... I traced the pid.... apparently... I had an old docker experiment that was launching containers at boot without me being aware.   I removed the containers... all is well in memory land... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it wasn't Vbox hogging memory (this time.)

For anyone, who wants an easy and straightforward way of knowing exactly what processes are running in your swap memory I suggest `sudo apt-get install smem`

That little clearly lists every process using swap which is how I was able to discover that a 6 month old docker experiment was still launching at boot and hiding in my swap memory, so I couldn't directly "see" its memory via `top` or `htop`.